# Sum data in two tables and insert it in another one without duplucate ID

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have 3 tables..

`House1` `House2` `results`

```
    house1
    ID,  Name,  Monday,  Tuesday
     1   john     1         1
     2   jack     1         0
```

and

```
    House2
    ID,  Name,  Monday,  Tuesday
     3   Dan      0         0
     1   John     1         0
```

and I want to fill the `results` table, something like this:

```
    results
    ID,  Name,  Total
    1    john     3
    2    jack     1
    3    dan      0
```

im using the IIF() to count the days.. but it made dupicate rows
im using something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO results (ID, name, total)
SELECT ID, name, IIf([house1.monday]>0,1,0)+
                 IIf([house2.monday]>0,1,0)+
                 IIf([house1.tuesday]>0,1,0)+
                 IIF([house2.tuesday]>0,1,0) as TOTAL
FROM house1,house2
WHERE House1.ID = House2.ID
```

that clearly doesn't work, because it only insert the data of `john`.

Comment: Can you assume the values in the house tables are always `0` and `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recognize the problem with your query.  The inner join only keeps matching rows.

You can keep all rows by using `union all` instead.  The following calculates the `total` for each table and then uses `aggregation` to sum them:

```
INSERT INTO results(ID, name, total)
    SELECT ID, name, SUM(Total) as TOTAL
    FROM ((select h1.id, IIf([h1.monday]>0,1,0) + IIf([h1.tuesday]>0,1,0) as Total
           from house1 h1
          ) union all
          (select h2.id, IIf([h2.monday]>0,1,0) + IIf([h2.tuesday]>0,1,0) as Total
           from house2 h2
          )
         ) h
    group by id, name;
```

EDIT

You changed the question in your comment.  However, you would just do the same thing, defining the columns that you need in the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO results(ID, name, totalMonday, totalTuesday, total)
    SELECT ID, name, SUM(Monday), SUM(Tuesday), SUM(Monday)+Sum(Tuesday) as TOTAL
    FROM ((select h1.id, IIf([h1.monday]>0,1,0) as Monday, IIf([h1.tuesday]>0,1,0) as Tuesday
           from house1 h1
          ) union all
          (select h2.id, IIf([h2.monday]>0,1,0) as Monday, IIf([h2.tuesday]>0,1,0) as Tuesday
           from house2 h2
          )
         ) h
    group by id, name;
```

Comment: ok it works.. but  what if i have in the results table, 2 fields called "Total_monday and "Total_Tuesday"..   and it need to be filled too

Comment: ok  when i tried to execute it.. it sended me "enter parameter value "house2.monday"... and  it doesnt work with double parenthesis.. i had to delete it and let only 2

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(Monday)+SUM(Tuesday) as Total
FROM
(
SELECT ID, Name, Monday, Tuesday
FROM House1
Union ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Monday, Tuesday
FROM House2
) a
Group BY a.ID, a.Name
```

Comment: let me see... i dont understand why is that "a" there?

Comment: @KeyKenkay . . . That is called a table alias.  It is used to give a name to the subquery.

Comment: nvm i got it..  but what if in the results table i have 2 fields called "total_house1" and "total_house2"...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO results
SELECT Id, Name, SUM(Monday) + SUM (Tuesday)
FROM (
SELECT Id, Name, Monday, Tuesday FROM house1
UNION
SELECT Id, Name, Monday, Tuesday FROM house2)
group by Id;
```

You can go to http://www.compileonline.com/execute_sql_online.php and try this code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS House1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS House2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;

CREATE TABLE House1(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Monday integer,  Tuesday integer);
CREATE TABLE House2(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Monday integer,  Tuesday integer);
CREATE TABLE results(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, Total integer);

INSERT INTO House1 VALUES(1,'john', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO House1 VALUES(2,'jack', 1, 0);
INSERT INTO House2 VALUES(3,'Dan', 0, 0);
INSERT INTO House2 VALUES(1,'john', 1, 0);
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO results
SELECT Id, Name, SUM(Monday) + SUM (Tuesday)
FROM (
SELECT Id, Name, Monday, Tuesday FROM house1
UNION
SELECT Id, Name, Monday, Tuesday FROM house2)
GROUP BY Id;

SELECT * FROM results;
```